# WxPython GUI programming - NameError: name "self" is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, nameerror

I'm creating a program to edit a .txt file.

I have 2 files inside a folder:

> gui.py & edit_text.py

Here's the code for **gui.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import wx
import wx.xrc

class Main ( wx.Frame ):
    
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Editor MAVB", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 250,180 ), style = wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 250,180 ), wx.Size( 250,180 ) )
        
        layout_sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        
        self.text1 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Escolha o arquivo que será editado:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.text1.Wrap( -1 )
        layout_sizer.Add( self.text1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        
        self.filePicker = wx.FilePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Selecione um arquivo", u"*.txt", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 210,-1 ), wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.FLP_FILE_MUST_EXIST|wx.FLP_SMALL )
        layout_sizer.Add( self.filePicker, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        
        self.null_text = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.null_text.Wrap( -1 )
        layout_sizer.Add( self.null_text, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        
        self.edit_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Alterar arquivo", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        layout_sizer.Add( self.edit_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        
        self.status_text = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Aguardando arquivo...", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.status_text.Wrap( -1 )
        layout_sizer.Add( self.status_text, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        
        
        self.SetSizer( layout_sizer )
        self.Layout()
        
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        
        # Connect Events
        self.edit_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.editar_txt )
    
    def __del__( self ):
        pass
    
    
    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def editar_txt( self, event ):
        event.Skip()
```

And here is the code for **edit_txt.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gui
import wx

class MyFrame(gui.Main):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        gui.Main.__init__(self, parent)
        
    infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()
    outfile_path = infile[:len(infile)-4] + "_editado.txt"
    
    def editar_txt(self, infile):
        outfile = []
        with open(infile) as f:
            for line in f:
                line_ed = line.replace("|VENDAS|0|", "|VENDAS|2|")
                outfile.append(line_ed)
        with open(outfile_path, "w") as g:
            for line in outfile:
                g.write(line)

        f.close()
        g.close()
  
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        print("\n----------------------------------------\nEditor MAVB - inicializado com sucesso. \n----------------------------------------")
        return True
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(redirect=False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I enter into the program folder and run **edit_txt.py**, I got the following error:

```
Error in line 
infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

1. I've created a Main class in gui.py
2. Imported gui.py script into edit_txt.py
3. Created a inherited MyFrame class from the gui.Main class
4. Initialized MyFrame class as soon as I open the program
5. Then I tried to get the infile path using the command: `infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()`

**Questions:**

> Why isn't this working?
>
> How can I make it work?

Comment: If I put 1 more tab starting from `infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()` and going to `g.close()`, the code at least shows the GUI window when I run it...

Comment: Your line `infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()` is badly indented, and lives outside of the scope of any function, hence `self` is not defined. Simply indent it and the next one, and this error should at least disappear.

Comment: @BenjaminAudren, I've indented the lines with `infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()`and `outfile_path = infile[:len(infile)-4] + "_editado.txt"`, then I've asked my code to print these variables. The variable ìnfile` is equal to "" and the variable `outfile_path` is equal to "_editado.txt". I guess it's because first the user must browse the file to set a value to `wx.FilePickerCtrl`. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: Oh, and after indenting it and executing it, when I press the `editar_txt()` button i get the following error: `TypeError: editar_txt() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. My guess it's because `GetTextCtrlValue()`is returning something like `r"C:/folder"`, but idk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance property inherited from gui.Main as a class property. Generally speaking, you are trying to statically access a non-static property.

If you define *infile* and *outfile_path* as instance properties for *MyFrame*, you can then access them with *self.Property*.

(Please note that this way you need to change references to the *editar_txt* method where it is referenced, because the argument is no longer necessary.)

Below the modified MyFrame class in **edit_txt.py** :

```
class MyFrame(gui.Main):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        gui.Main.__init__(self, parent)

        self.infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()
        self.outfile_path = self.infile[:len(self.infile)-4] + "_editado.txt"

    def editar_txt(self):
        outfile = []
        with open(self.infile) as f:
            for line in f:
                line_ed = line.replace("|VENDAS|0|", "|VENDAS|2|")
                outfile.append(line_ed)
        with open(self.outfile_path, "w") as g:
            for line in outfile:
                g.write(line)

        f.close()
        g.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't it working? Because the following line:

```
infile = self.filePicker.GetTextCtrlValue()
```

is outside any function, and is in the class definition. It is trying to execute this line *as the class is being defined* to create an `infile` attribute on the class, and as `self` is not defined at this time, it complains about `self` not being defined.

How can you make it work? Presumably, you intended that line and the one after it to be in your `__init__()` method. Indent them accordingly.